# WPF C# How can I use a common ObservableCollection in two ViewModels?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I got a question about how can I use a common ObservableCollection in two ViewModels in WPF C#?

I got two views, first view consist of a a observablecollection of categories used in a combobox in some form. The second view is a window which enable adding, editing and removal of categories. Now I'm retrieving the categories for both views separately, but I want to combine and use a common observable collection, in order to get the new changes when I added, change or remove categories in the second view.

Both Views and viewmodels is controlled by a mainviewmodel:

```
    public viewModel1 viewModel1 { get; set; }
    public ViewModel2 ViewModel2 { get; set; }

    public MainViewModel()
    {
        this.InitializeCommands();
        this.viewModel1 = new viewModel1();
        this.ViewModel2 = new ViewModel2();


        this.ViewModel2.OnChangedCategory += (s, e) =>
        {
            this.viewModel1.Categories = GetCategories();
        };
    }
```

ViewModel for View1:

```
public ObservableCollection<Categories> GetCategories
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._getCategories == null)
            {
                this._getCategories = methods.GetCategories();
            }

            return this._getCategories ;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._getCategories != value)
            {
                this._getCategories = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("GetCategories");
            }
        }
    }
```

ViewModel for View2:

```
public ObservableCollection<Categories> GetCategories
    {
        get
        {
            if (this._getCategories == null)
            {
                this._getCategories = methods.GetCategories();
            }

            return this._getCategories ;
        }
        set
        {
            if (this._getCategories != value)
            {
                this._getCategories = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("GetCategories");
            }
        }
    }
```

In theory, they are both identical, just two different observable collection in two viewmodels, I want to use the same observable collection in both views, if it's in the first or second ViewModel doesn't matter. But it makes maybe more sense if it's in viewmodel 2. Let's say if I decide have a common categories observable collection in ViewModel 2, how can Viewmodel 1 use this observable collection from ViewModel 2 and still be in sync upon changes?

How can I do this?

Comment: Create a model class for the data and hand it over to both view models

Comment: Create base class to handle that

Comment: @nicolas  does updating the class update both viewmodels?

Comment: Are the View's DataContext set to MainViewModel.ViewModel1 & MainViewModel.ViewModel2 or directly to the individual ViewModels? Could you not have the ObservableCollection in the MainViewModel and bind to that?

Comment: @Fredrik Linger If the model class exposes a property holding your data and both view models refer to this property, they all work with the same data (e. g. `ObservableCollection`), which means if one of them makes changes, all of them "see" the changes (and get notified in the `ObservableCollection` case)

Answer (score 0):

You could make it a resource and then any code could get at it.
The sample associated with this article has two pairs of usercontrols share two such collections and sounds fairly similar to your requirement.

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/29859.wpf-tips-bind-to-current-item-of-collection.aspx

Comment: Hi, I tested this method, but it doesn't seem like I manage to get the item in the collection to update properly. Can the items in the collection be manipulated directly?

Comment: It's an observablecollection, you can do anything to it that you can do to an observablecollection. The sample allows you to edit in one usercontrol and see the results in the other.

Comment: It's a ListCollectionView? My combobox is using the ListCollectionView or should it use Observable? The tutorial was a bit confusing, could you be kind and provide me some code example?

Comment: Working code is here https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/Dynamic-XAML-Composed-View-e087f3c1